# Athena looking for records with different start dates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a lot of customer files with I customer data that includes a customer id which can have multiple service points. A service point can have a meter and a meter can have a meter install date:

| Cust | Service Point | Meter ID | Meter Install Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20201005 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20201005 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20201005 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20150101 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20150101 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20150101 |
| 1 | A2 | AM2 | 20220110 |
| 1 | A2 | AM2 | 20220110 |
| 1 | A2 | AM2 | 20220110 |
| 1 | A2 | AM21 | 20230215 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20200509 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20200509 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20200509 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20221013 |

I'm trying to find the number of meters that have a multiple install dates.  It is not uncommon to have multiple rows where these field's information is duplicated.  As I try different strategies I get different answers so I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried:

```sql
select customer_id, service_point_id, secondary_sp_id
from customer
where secondary_sp_id in (
  select secondary_sp_id
  from customer
  group by secondary_sp_id
  having length(secondary_sp_id) > 1 and count(distinct meter_install_date) > 1
```

```sql
select customer_id, service_point_id, secondary_sp_id, meter_install_date
from customer
where secondary_sp_id in (
select secondary_sp_id
from customer
group by secondary_sp_id having count(distinct meter_install_date) > 1 )
```

```sql
select a.service_point_id, a.secondary_sp_id, a.meter_install_date 
from customer a, customer b 
where a.service_point_id = b.service_point_id 
and a.secondary_sp_id = b.secondary_sp_id 
and a.meter_install_date != b.meter_install_date 
group by a.service_point_id, a.secondary_sp_id, a.meter_install_date
```

I would expect to get back:

| Cust | Service Point | Meter ID | Meter Install Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20201005 |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 20150101 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20200509 |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 20221013 |

I don't think I'm handling when a service point has multiple meters and one of those meters has multiple start dates.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we have enough information of your data or schema, such as how "secondardy_sp_id" fits into this. No details were provided on that column nor the prod_peco_customer table.

If we assume your data appears like your first formatted section in the question, then the following CTE would work as-is.

```
create table customer (
  cust integer, 
  service_point varchar(5), 
  meter_id varchar(5), 
  meter_install_date date
  );
  
insert into customer values 
(1, 'A1', 'AM1', '20201005'),
(1, 'A1', 'AM1', '20150101'),
(1, 'A2', 'AM2', '20230110');
```

---

```
with target_meters as (
  select meter_id
  from customer
  group by meter_id
  having count(distinct meter_install_date) > 1
  )
select c.*
from customer c
join target_meters t
  on c.meter_id = t.meter_id;
```

| cust | service_point | meter_id | meter_install_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |

---

But I kinda doubt your data looks like this even though you formatted it that way in the question. Adjust accordingly, but main point is that you could use a sub-query or CTE for identifying your meters with multiple install dates.

**----------Update-----------**

Based on the updated sample data, then you would simply need to change `select c.*` to `select distinct c.*` such as this...

```
with target_meters as (
  select meter_id
  from customer
  group by meter_id
  having count(distinct meter_install_date) > 1
  )
select distinct c.*
from customer c
join target_meters t
  on c.meter_id = t.meter_id
order by 1,2,3,4
```

| cust | service_point | meter_id | meter_install_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1 | A1 | AM1 | 2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 2020-05-09T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1 | A3 | AM3 | 2022-10-13T00:00:00.000Z |

Comment: Sorry about the table confusion, they should all just read customer.  The customer table has a few dozen other columns that will result in duplicates of of the columns I'm interested in.  A customer can have multiple service points, a service point can have 1 meter_id at a time, and a meter should only have one meter install date.  They don't, which is the problem.  I'm trying to figure out how often it is happening.  I'll update the table to make more in line with what it looks like.

Comment: If you just want to know how often, then just use the CTE part of my answer, but change to `select count(meter_id)...`